# How to get Sim card details using ionic 2

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I installed

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-sim

npm install --save @ionic-native/sim
```

imported in app.module

```
import { Sim } from '@ionic-native/sim';

providers[
     Sim 
]

import { Sim } from "@ionic-native/sim";


    getSimData() {
        try {
          let simPermission = this.sim.requestReadPermission();

            let simData = this.sim.getSimInfo();
            this.simInfo = simData;
           this.cards = simData.cards;
            console.log(simData);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);

      }
```

Not getting sims cards is there any other try to get the  list of sim cards details by using different plugin

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sim/.. the api returns _promises_

Comment: in this i am not getting sim card details in promise  i am getting this  callState:0 carrierName:"" countryCode:"" dataActivity:0 deviceId:"352196070741525" deviceSoftwareVersion:"05" isNetworkRoaming:false mcc:"" mnc:"" networkType:0 phoneType:1 simState:1

Comment: I want how many sims user using and net work

Comment: Ref https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sim/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
constructor(public sim: Sim) { }

this.sim.getSimInfo().then(info => {
      console.log('Sim info: ', info);
}).catch(err => {
      console.log('Unable to get sim info: ', err);
});
```

Comment: How to get sim card details hear

Comment: alert('Sim info: '+ JSON.stringify(info)) here info variable contains all the required information about a sim card

Comment: can u say how to get sim card details from this so that i can use the same methods

Comment: these are the details  callState:0
carrierName:""
countryCode:""
dataActivity:0
deviceId:"352196070741525"
deviceSoftwareVersion:"05"
isNetworkRoaming:false
mcc:""
mnc:""
networkType:0
phoneType:1
simState:1

Comment: dear sir i am not getting card details atol so pleas help me out

Answer (score 0):

If you want how many sims users using then requires **Android API 22** you have that?

The return object of **getSimInfo** the details of the available sim cards in an array (cards).

Check https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-sim#under-the-hood